# Codename one iOS build fails on server - Multiple main classes

Tags: ios, codenameone

this is the first time I'm trying to build for ios and the server reports the following error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Multiple main
>   classes: MacrosBootstrap and
>   [my app name]Stub     at
>   com.codename1.tools.translator.ByteCodeClass.addMethod(ByteCodeClass.java:87)
>     at com.codename1.tools.translator.Parser.visitMethod(Parser.java:640)
>     at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.b(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.codename1.tools.translator.Parser.parse(Parser.java:65)

I believe the offending MacrosBootstrap class is the one from the mirah plugin I'm using to map POJOs to/from json.

The Android build works fine.

Any advise ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I'm using https://github.com/shannah/cn1-mirah-json-macros/blob/master/docs/json.md for json mapping, and I have a different project where I generate all the mappers and then export it as a cn1lib into the main project. I suppose the MacrosBootrap class is used in the process o generating the mappers but is useless at runtime, so all I had to do is exclude it from the jar and problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

That means `MacrosBootstrap` has a `public static void main(String[])` method. Only one main method can exist in our iOS VM and we need to generate that so there is a conflict.